# Migrate a Window special tool to macOS, this tool can modify the attributes of other application

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

I have a Windows tool, it allows we move cursor, click on any third-party window on the desktop to get their related window handle, then we can use those handles to change the attribute of the third-party window such as alpha, WS_VISIBLE, cloak etc of the selected window, is it possible to implement those features in macOS?

The Windows APIs used: WindowFromPoint, SetCapture, GetCapture, SetWindowLong, DwmSetWindowAttribute, ModifyWindow, FindWindow etc,
Is there any mapped macOS APIs for those purposes?

I planned to use Swift and Objective-C, but not sure if it is possible or not

No code yet, just for investigation

not yet

Comment: Looks like it is possible via QT, anyway, I don't use QT

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to port all those features, the closest example will be SonOfGrab